iOS: How to show an introductory offer with promotional offer(if there is introductory offer not need to show promotional offer)
I have an promotional offer for a 1 week trial for the app users who is subscribing for the very first time. Here I need to show an additional offer only for the users who are subscribing on certain days. So I am going with the introductory offer.
For ex) If I am giving the offer for the app for 1 week or one month who are subscribing the app with a special offer for a certain day alone. Here I need to show this offer for few days and revert back the app to an original promotional offer after this special offer.
Is there any way to make this using the SKProductsRequest using the StoreKit.
